# Typeorm: Query to check if all the values exist in the many-to-many relation?

Tags: node.js, typescript, orm, typeorm

I have a **conversation** entity with many-to-many relation with **members**. I am trying to return a conversation with exact specified users. My code below works but its just too much and I want to simplify it.

conversation.entity.ts

```js
@Entity()
export class Conversation {

    readonly __typename: string = 'Conversation';

    @ManyToMany(() => User)
    @JoinTable()
    members: User[];

    @ManyToMany(() => Order)
    @JoinTable()
    orders: Order[];

    @ManyToMany(() => Product)
    @JoinTable()
    products: Product[];

    @ManyToMany(() => Request)
    @JoinTable()
    requests: Request[];
}
```

I have a function that gets all the conversation ids with member one and then gets all conversation ids with member two. Then I just filter both the returned ID arrays to get the common one which should be at most one.

Function to get conversation:

```js
async findOneByAllMembers(ctx: RequestContext, input: FindConversationInput) {
        const { memberUserIds } = input;
        if (memberUserIds.length !== 2) {
            throw new UserInputError('Member IDs are not equal to 2');
        }

        const conversationFromMemberOne = await this.connection
            .getRepository(ctx, Conversation)
            .createQueryBuilder('conversation')
            .select('conversation.id')
            .innerJoin('conversation.members', 'members')
            .where('members.id = :memberId', { memberId: memberUserIds[0] })
            .getMany()
            .then(items => {
                const ids = items.map(val => val.id);
                return ids;
            });

        const conversationFromMemberTwo = await this.connection
            .getRepository(ctx, Conversation)
            .createQueryBuilder('conversation')
            .select('conversation.id')
            .innerJoin('conversation.members', 'members')
            .where('members.id = :memberId', { memberId: memberUserIds[1] })
            .getMany()
            .then(items => {
                const ids = items.map(val => val.id);
                return ids;
            });

        const filteredArray = conversationFromMemberOne.filter(value =>
            conversationFromMemberTwo.includes(value),
        );

        console.log(filteredArray);

        return filteredArray;
    }
```

This code works but I want to limit my sql queries to one. Is there a way to a conversation with both the members in it?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried locally and this should work:

```js
const conversations: Conversation[] = await this.connection
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .select('conversation.id')
    .from(Conversation, 'conversation')
    .innerJoin('conversation.members', 'member')
    .where('member.id = :id', { id: memberUserIds[0] })
    .andWhere(
      (qb) =>
        `conversation.id IN ${qb
          .subQuery()
          .select('conversation.id')
          .from(Conversation, 'conversation')
          .innerJoin('conversation.members', 'member')
          .where('member.id = :id', { id: memberUserIds[1] })
          .getQuery()}`,
    )
    .getMany();

const conversationsIds: number[] = conversations.map((conversation) => conversation.id);
```

Firstly, select all conversation ids of the first user.

Secondly, "filter" them by checking if the id is *IN* the ones of the second user.

Last but not least, map the result (`conversations`) to obtain only an array of conversation ids (`conversationsIds`) that is a "pure" array of numbers.

I'm using **subquery**; see [this](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/using-subqueries) for more information.

PS: Remember that a query could fail so surround it with `try` and `catch`.